# Unable to do Arduino Mega to Arduino Mega serial communication

Tags: arduino, serial-port, embedded

Based on the circuit below, I tried hooking up two **Arduino Mega** for serial communication.

[image]

The code for sender:

```cpp
char mystr[3] = "Hello"; //String data

void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.write(mystr, 5); //Write the serial data
  delay(1000);
}
```

The code for receiver:

```cpp
char mystr[5]; //Initialized variable to store received data

void setup() {
  // Begin the Serial at 9600 Baud
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.readBytes(mystr, 5); //Read the serial data and store in var
  delay(1000);
}
```

There is no output in the Serial console of Arduino. Could someone please inform me of the possible cause and solution for the same. If I've missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point let me know in the comments.

Comment: Unrelated but your declaration for the string to send makes no sense.

Comment: How do you expect to put 5 characters + nul terminator into an array of 3 characters? The string doesn't even fit into an array of 5 characters. `readBytes` doesn't nul terminate the string. And how exactly did you wire the Megas? Your image shows Unos.

Comment: @gre_gor As mention in the question used exactly the same method to wire MEGA on **Serial** the code is from this [https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/harshmangukiya/serial-communication-between-two-arduino-boards-d423e9]

Comment: That tutorial is awful.

Comment: you need to check if data is available at the serial port using `if(Serial.available)` before reading data from the serial buffer

Comment: @IkennaAnthonyOkafor  I tried it but it's returning -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood this right you have one Arduino connected to your pc and to another Arduino?

The problem is that you need to specify which Serial port to use:
That is rather easy, just type `Serial1` or `Serial2` instead of just `Serial`. That allows you to open 2 Serial ports: One to your other Arduino and one to your Computer for Displaying the results !

LINK: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MultiSerialMega

Comment: why is okey for Uno but not for Mega

Answer (score 0):

You need to check available data from serial:

```
void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            // read the incoming byte:
            Serial.readBytes(mystr, 5);
            Serial.print("I received: ");
            Serial.println(mystr, DEC);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you receive `-1` you don't have any serial data. Also you send by `Serial.write(mystr, 5);` as a string but want to read binary data `Serial.readBytes(mystr, 5);`, you need to call `Serial.Read()`

Comment: but there is no output in the Rx buffer